# What's the difference between "Write-Host", "Write-Output", or "[console]::WriteLine"?

Tags: powershell

There are a number of different ways to output messages. What is the effective difference between outputting something via `Write-Host`, `Write-Output`, or `[console]::WriteLine`?

I also notice that if I use:

```
write-host "count=" + $count
```

The `+` gets included in the output. Why's that? Shouldn't the expression be evaluated to produce a single concatenated string before it gets written out?

Comment: `Write-Output` when you're emitting results. `Write-Host` when you're emitting logging information. Never use `[console]::writeline()`.

Comment: @JohnL why should we never use [console]::writeline() ?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave Because you have Write-Host.... Ok, I may have been under some impression that it showed a new console window (it was quite a long time ago). That doesn't happen, but the fact remains that it's not the powershell idiom and there's nothing you can do with `[console]::writeline("hello world")` that you can't do with `Write-Host "hello world"`. Another, better, more recently applicable answer is that `write-host` wraps `write-information` so its data gets put on a stream like `write-error` so you can capture it and use it elsewhere. `[console]::writeline()` does not do that

Answer (score 300, accepted):

`Write-Output` should be used when you want to send data on in the pipe line, but not necessarily want to display it on screen. The pipeline will eventually write it to `out-default` if nothing else uses it first.

`Write-Host` should be used when you want to do the opposite.

`[console]::WriteLine` is essentially what `Write-Host` is doing behind the scenes.

Run this demonstration code and examine the result.

```
function Test-Output {
    Write-Output "Hello World"
}

function Test-Output2 {
    Write-Host "Hello World" -foreground Green
}

function Receive-Output {
    process { Write-Host $_ -foreground Yellow }
}

#Output piped to another function, not displayed in first.
Test-Output | Receive-Output

#Output not piped to 2nd function, only displayed in first.
Test-Output2 | Receive-Output 

#Pipeline sends to Out-Default at the end.
Test-Output
```

You'll need to enclose the concatenation operation in parentheses, so that PowerShell processes the concatenation before tokenizing the parameter list for `Write-Host`, or use string interpolation

```
write-host ("count=" + $count)
# or
write-host "count=$count"
```

BTW - Watch this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Erik-Meijer-and-Jeffrey-Snover-Inside-PowerShell/) of Jeffrey Snover explaining how the pipeline works. Back when I started learning PowerShell I found this to be the most useful explanation of how the pipeline works.

Comment: In an Azure WebJob [console]::WriteLine works but Write-Host will result in an error: The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred while setting character attributes for the console output buffer. Don't ask me why.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `Write-Output` is the default e.g. if you have a PsObject and you just spit it out to the screen by doing this `$object` it will actually do the same thing as this `Write-Output $object`. Might be worth mentioning

Comment: There is new guidance: avoid using `Write-Output` when possible. See https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/issues/46#issuecomment-469449001

> Use return only for ending execution.

> Avoid Write-Output (...). Instead, when you want to make output clearer, just assign output to a relevantly named variable. and put that a variable on a line by itself to signal explicit output.

> Write-Output -NoEnumerate is broken on PowerShell 6 and has been for 16 months or longer -- there's no plan to fix it. In summary:

> DO NOT USE Write-Output -- EVER.

Comment: Since PowerShell 5.0, `Write-Host` no longer writes directly to the console. Instead, it writes to the new [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/whats-new/informationstream-overview?view=powershell-7.3), which _may_ end up in the console, if not redirected (e.g. `Write-Host 'foo' 6>&1 | Set-Content file.txt`).

Answer (score 30):

Apart from what Andy mentioned, there is another difference which could be important - write-host directly writes to the host and return nothing, meaning that you can't redirect the output, e.g., to a file.

```
---- script a.ps1 ----
write-host "hello"
```

Now run in PowerShell:

```
PS> .\a.ps1 > someFile.txt
hello
PS> type someFile.txt
PS>
```

As seen, you can't redirect them into a file. This maybe surprising for someone who are not careful.

But if switched to use write-output instead, you'll get redirection working as expected.

Comment: It's possible to capture Write-Host Output if you use Start-Process Powershell .\a.ps1 -RedirectStandardOutput somefile.txt There's trouble with encoding, though (file will be in SystemDefaultEncoding).

Answer (score 17):

Here's another way to accomplish the equivalent of Write-Output.  Just put your string in quotes:

```
"count=$count"
```

You can make sure this works the same as Write-Output by running this experiment:

```
"blah blah" > out.txt

Write-Output "blah blah" > out.txt

Write-Host "blah blah" > out.txt
```

The first two will output "blah blah" to out.txt, but the third one won't.

"help Write-Output" gives a hint of this behavior:

> This cmdlet is typically used in scripts to display strings and other
>   objects on the console. However, because the default behavior is to
>   display the objects at the end of a pipeline, it is generally not
>   necessary to use the cmdlet.

In this case, the string itself "count=$count" is the object at the end of a pipeline, and is displayed.

Answer (score 9):

For usages of `Write-Host`, [`PSScriptAnalyzer`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) produces the following diagnostic:

> Avoid using `Write-Host` because it might not work in all hosts, does not work when there is no host, and (prior to PS 5.0) cannot be suppressed, captured, or redirected. Instead, use `Write-Output`, `Write-Verbose`, or `Write-Information`.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/361dbf5caf3848e381a999570d971633ca40b818/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingWriteHost.md) behind that rule for more information. Excerpts for posterity:

> The use of `Write-Host` is greatly discouraged unless in the use of commands with the `Show` verb. The `Show` verb explicitly means "show on the screen, with no other possibilities".
>
> Commands with the `Show` verb do not have this check applied.

Jeffrey Snover has a blog post [Write-Host Considered Harmful](https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) in which he claims *Write-Host is almost always the wrong thing to do because it interferes with automation* and provides more explanation behind the diagnostic, however the above is a good summary.

Answer (score 3):

From my testing Write-Output and [Console]::WriteLine() perform much better than Write-Host.

Depending on how much text you need to write out this may be important.

Below if the result of 5 tests each for Write-Host, Write-Output and [Console]::WriteLine().

In my limited experience, I've found when working with any sort of real world data I need to abandon the cmdlets and go straight for the lower level commands to get any decent performance out of my scripts.

```
measure-command {$count = 0; while ($count -lt 1000) { Write-Host "hello"; $count++ }}

1312ms
1651ms
1909ms
1685ms
1788ms


measure-command { $count = 0; while ($count -lt 1000) { Write-Output "hello"; $count++ }}

97ms
105ms
94ms
105ms
98ms


measure-command { $count = 0; while ($count -lt 1000) { [console]::WriteLine("hello"); $count++ }}

158ms
105ms
124ms
99ms
95ms
```

Comment: `Write-Output` and `Write-Host` serve different purposes, so there is no point in comparing their performance.
Yes, direct use of .NET types and their methods is faster, but you miss out on the higher-level features that PowerShell cmdlets can provide.
`[Console]::WriteLine()` is akin to `Write-Host` in the case at hand, but won't work in all circumstances, because not all PowerShell hosts are _consoles_.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Console]::WriteLine() - you should use it if you are going to use pipelines in CMD (not in powershell). Say you want your ps1 to stream a lot of data to stdout, and some other utility to consume/transform it. If you use Write-Host in the script it will be much slower.