# Powershell Loop doesn't wait for command completion

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, cmd

I have create a little script to run and print out whenever I have a driver installed, The problem I am having is when I call `Compare-Object` the script seems to hang and only run this code on quit.

I have already tried `| out-null` and `waitjob` with no avail

```
$global:drivers = $null

function checkDrivers{
    $temp = Driverquery.exe /V

    # testing
    $temp += "newDriver     SMS Process Event Driv SMS Process Event Driv Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        8,192             8,192       0          03/08/2011 8:56:26 AM  C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\prepdrv.sys          4,096"

    if($temp.Length -eq $global:drivers.Length){
        return
    }

    Write-Output "[---] Driver Installed"
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $global:drivers -DifferenceObject $temp
    $global:drivers = $temp
}

Write-Output "[+] Parsing initial drivers..."
$global:drivers = Driverquery.exe /V
Write-Output "[+] Parsing complete`n"
Write-Output "[+] Press 'q' to quit"
Write-Output "[+] Scanning for Driver Installs..."
while ($true){
    if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and ("q" -eq $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character)) {
        Write-Host "Exiting now..." -Background DarkRed
        break;
    }

    checkDrivers
    start-sleep -seconds 5
}
```

Here is my output, I expected the Object compare line to be executed before quit under [---] Driver Installed

```
[+] Parsing initial drivers...
[+] Parsing complete

[+] Press 'q' to quit
[+] Scanning for Driver Installs...
[---] Driver Installed

Exiting now...
InputObject                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                SideIndicator
-----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -------------
newDriver     SMS Process Event Driv SMS Process Event Driv Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        8,192             8,192       0          03/08/2011 8:56:26 AM  C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\prepdrv.sys          4,096 =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Exiting now..' line is appearing above the rest of the output because it's using `Write-Host` which [writes to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output) instead of `Write-Output` which writes to the pipeline. But the script is executing in the expected order.

Comment: How would I go about piping the command to Write-Host, I have tried ```Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $global:drivers -DifferenceObject $temp | Write-Host``` but it still seems to halt the program.

Comment: Nevermind I got it too work by changing everything else to write-output, thank you.