# How to Write Output of a PowerShell Command that uses a for-each loop to a text file?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to generate a file list in a text file using the below PowerShell Command and it generates an empty file every time.

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\transfer\SprintReporting\" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"} | % {Write-Host $_.FullName | Out-File D:\transfer\SprintReporting\file.txt -Append}
```

This script generates the output below but doesn't store it in the file. I have tried it with and without Append, inside and outside the loop scope, but nothing has worked so far. Any ideas what I might be missing here?

[image]

Comment: change `write-host` to `write-output`.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output

Comment: I suggest to simplify the last part like this: `% { Add-Content D:\transfer\SprintReporting\file.txt $_.FullName }`