# PowerShell Write-Host append to a text file

Tags: powershell

Im new in PowerShell and working on a script more than 500 lines.
I use the `write-host` command often. And now Im working on doing the Logging part.
Also, sorry for the bad English.

I want the script to save every `write-host` command in a .txt,
append and still let the `write-host` command output passthrough to the Shell output.

Things I tried:

```
&{
# the script 
} *>> $logPath
```

```
Start-Transcript -Path $logPath
# the script 
Stop-Transcript
```

It works but its not letting the output passthrough.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. If I replace `# the script ` with `Write-Host 'Hello World'`, it writes `Hello World` to the display. With PowerShell version and [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) are you using?

Comment: The `Tee-Object` cmdlet is designed for this. It passes output both to the console and to a file.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that would be to be to use [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet by wrapping your whole script like this:-

```
@(
Write-Output "######### Loop 1 #########"
foreach ($i in (1..5))
{
    Write-Output $i "--> Loop1"
}

Write-Output "######### Loop 2 #########"
foreach ($i in (6..11))
{
    Write-Output $i "--> Loop2"
}

Write-Output "######### Loop 3 #########"
foreach ($i in (12..15))
{
    Write-Output $i "--> Loop3"
}
) | Out-file $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Output.txt -width 50
```

Use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host` as `Write-Host` writes to the console itself where as `Write-Output` sends the output to the pipeline. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output#:%7E:text=In%20a%20nutshell%2C%20Write%2DHost,is%20implicitly%20called%20for%20you.) for details.