# Print out the number of cpu cores

Tags: powershell

I want to print out the number of cores.

```
$N_cores = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | ft NumberOfCores 
Write-Host $N_cores | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores
```

This give me following:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Mi
crosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Micros
oft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

How can I display the NumberOfCores?

Answer (score 3):

you need to extract just the value of the cores, try this

```
$N_cores = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores

Write-Host "Number of cores is: $N_cores"
```

Answer (score 3):

The confusing ouput you're seeing comes from `ft` (alias for `Format-Table`).

To trim the number of properties you want from `Get-WmiObject`, use `Select-Object` instead.

For example, to store the `NumberOfCores` property in `$N_cores`, and subsequently display only its raw value you could do:

```
# This will create an object with a `NumberOfCores` property
$N_cores = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor |Select-Object NumberOfCores 

# print just the value of the property
Write-Host $N_cores.NumberOfCores
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues here

1. You are calling Format-Table prior to using the content elsewhere, [Format-Table returns an output of format objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2#outputs)
2. You are Piping your Write-Output to Select-Object, which is generally not how you want to got about this...

I suggest you follow the best practice of [Filter Left, Format Right](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1313038-filter-left-format-right)

When you pass objects through the pipe to another function, that function attempts to interpret those objects' properties as arguments. If you examine Format-Table output, it no-longer has the NumberOfCores property. That property was a member of the Win32_processor object type.

[You cannot pipe output from Write-Host, as it does not return anything to the pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2#outputs)

Ultimately the code that you would want is

```
$N_cores = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores
Format-Table $N_cores |Write-Host
```

---

It should also be mentioned that if you intend to do anything with this script besides print to the console, you should not use Format-Table or Write-Host, instead use
`Write-Output $N_cores
as your second line. This will write the result not only to the console, but also pass the objects in the $N_cores variable to the pipeline
[Write-Host vs Write-Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output)