# PowerShell output not expected

Tags: powershell

Why does the following PowerShell 5.1 statement produce output on 2 lines

```
Write-Output ($results | Measure-Object).Count ' rows returned'
```

Output

```
11
 rows returned
```

More context:

```
$results = Get-Service -ComputerName $computers -DisplayName *Transportation* | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} 
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Output ($results | Measure-Object).Count ' rows returned'
```

Comment: The question should be what need is there to use `Write-Output` when this is already implicit for PowerShell. The reason you see them in new lines is because `InputObject` is decorated with `ValueFromRemainingArguments` so you're actually passing an array to the cmdlet and the cmdlet is outputting exactly that

Comment: `"$(($results | Measure-Object).Count) rows returned"`

Comment: Rod, I've added additional background information to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Given PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior**, **there's rarely a good reason to use 
[`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)** - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for background information.

Thus, combined with the fact that you don't need [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) to get the count of objects, you can simplify to one of the following, both of which *implicitly* output the resulting string, which by default prints to the display:

```bash
# Expression
[string] $results.Count + ' rows returned'

# Expandable string.
"$($results.Count) rows returned.
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`Write-Output` accepts an open-ended number of arguments, which it outputs *one by one*, *as-is* - whatever data type they are.

Therefore, what `($results | Measure-Object).Count` evaluates to becomes the *first* output object - of type `[int]` - followed by `[string]` `' rows returned'`, and they print *separately*, on their own lines.

By contrast, [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) *would* have given you the desired *display* output (save for an extra space), as it *stringifies* all its arguments and prints *on the same line*, separated with spaces:

```bash
# Prints '42 and a half' to the display - does NOT produce *data output*
Write-Host (40 + 2) 'and a half'
```

However, note that **[`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)**, unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19754384/45375) for a juxtaposition of `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`.