# Powershell XML Validation

Tags: xml, validation, powershell, xsd

I'm trying to add XML validation to an existing Powershell script.  I've written code in C# as a proof of concept, but when I port to Powershell and use the same input files, I'm getting different results.  I'm using Powershell 3.0.

The C# code I have working is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace SchemaTest
{
    class Program
    {
        const string SCHEMA_PATH = @"C:\Test\test_schema.xsd";
        const string XML_PATH = @"C:\Test\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(SCHEMA_PATH);
            XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(
                schemaReader,
                (Object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Error reading schema file");
                }
            );
            schemaReader.Close();

            XmlReaderSettings rSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            rSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            rSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            rSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);
            rSettings.ValidationEventHandler += (Object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error validating XML file");
            };

            XmlReader configReader = XmlReader.Create(XML_PATH, rSettings);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(configReader);
            configReader.Close();

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a simple XSD schema and corresponding (invalid) XML file, which produces the expected "Error validating XML file" message from the `rSettings.ValidationEventHandler` when run with this code.

The corresponding Powershell code I've written is as follows:

```
$schemaReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create('C:\Test\test_schema.xsd')
[System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler]$schemaValidationHandler = { Write-Output "Error reading schema file" }
$schema = [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema]::Read($schemaReader, $schemaValidationHandler)
$schemaReader.Close()

$rSettings = New-Object -Type System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$rSettings.ValidationType = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema
$rSettings.ValidationFlags = $rSettings.ValidationFlags -bor [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ReportValidationWarnings
$rSettings.Schemas.Add($schema)
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $rSettings -EventName ValidationEventHandler -Action { Write-Output 'Error validating XML file' }

$configReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create('C:\Test\test.xml', $rSettings)

$doc = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($configReader)
$configReader.Close()
```

When I run this code against the same XSD and XML file, I don't get the "Error validating XML file" output as I expect.

To troubleshoot, I commented out the `Register-ObjectEvent` call, and verified that I am getting an exception when the `$doc.Load($configReader)` line is called. This leads me to think there is an issue with registering the event handler, but I can't seem to find an alternative.

For completeness, here are the XSD and XML files I'm using to test this:

test_schema.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.test.com"
xmlns="http://www.test.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
version="1.0.0">

   <xs:element name="root">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" />
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root
 xmlns="http://www.test.com"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 id="1">
   <name>Joe</name>
<!--   Comment out <age> tags for testing
   <age>20</age>  
-->
   <city>New York City</city>
 </root>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're using Write-Output in the event handler. If you try to change it to Write-Host (just for testing, not for keeping) you'll see that it gets written as expected.

Comment: @robert.westerlund That worked - I added the `Write-Output` because just quoting the string wasn't working...I didn't try the third (`Write-Host`) option. Why doesn't a `Write-Output` work in this case?  Since there is nothing else in the pipeline, why doesn't it get written to Out-Default when it's in a script block, as explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline)

Comment: Write-Output is generally the one you should use to get output from a method (except if your method is named with the verb Show, you probably shouldn't use the Write-Host cmdlet at all), or Write-Verbose, Write-Debug, Write-Warning or Write-Error, depending on what kind of output we're talking about. I'm not sure how Write-Output works with events though (haven't read about it or tried myself, yet), but I can imagine that they are run in a different scope or something (especially since you really don't know when an eventhandler will be called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Powershell, event handlers are run as Jobs.  As such, the results of their pipelines are not displayed on the screen the same as they would be in a pipeline in the main script.  The results of a pipeline of an executing job is available using the [Receive-Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849718.aspx) cmdlet.

Since `Write-Output` has the effect of displaying objects to the default outstream, it will only actually display to the screen when called from the main script.

This [chapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/11/powershell-eventing-quickstart.aspx) from the Powershell Cook book, does a decent job of explaining Powershell events and Jobs.