# PowerShell Write-Output inside "if" does not output anything

Tags: powershell

I am learning PowerShell recently, and found a behavior that I cannot understand. Let me explain in code below:

```
function func1()
{
    Write-Output "output from func1()"
    func2
    return $true
}

function func2()
{
    Write-Output "output from func2()"
    func3
}

function func3()
{
    Write-Output "output from func3()"
}

Write-Output "*** 1. run alone ****"
func1

Write-Output "*** 2. run inside if ****"
if (func1) {
    #do nothing
}
```

It is strange when func1 is called directly, it can output message as expected, but if put inside "if" statement, it will not. See output as below:

```
*** 1. run alone ****
output from func1()
output from func2()
output from func3()
True
*** 2. run inside if ****
```

You can see it's empty. Why is that, and how can I enable the output like the first example? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PowerShell functions are not like their traditional language counterparts: they can output multiple things. When you're using `Write-Output`, you are sending things down the pipeline, so `func1()` will return both a String and a Boolean. If you try this:

```
$return_values = func1;
$return_values | Get-Member
```

You will see that you get both `System.String` and `System.Boolean` objects in `$return_values`. Indeed the 'return' statement is more like an 'exit' or 'break' in traditional languages: it marks an exit point, but the function will actually return with whatever was already outputted (+ the optional return argument).

The quick fix to the issue is to change `Write-Output` to `Write-Host`, though they do slightly different things.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve desired results by replacing `Write-Output` with `Write-Host`. This is suitable *only* if your main concern is to produce output in the console as `Write-Host` does *not* go to stdout stream.

You can read more about difference between the 2 cmdlets in this SO thread :[Which should I use: "Write-Host", "Write-Output", or "[console]::WriteLine"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline)

Answer (score 0):

using this inline c# code can solve the problem

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp @"
using System; 
namespace Test 
{
public static class Write 
{ 
    public static void StdOut() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello world");
    }
}
}
"@;

function func1()
{
# Write-Output "output from func1()"
[Test.Write]::StdOut()
return $true
}

Write-Output "*** 1. run alone ****"
func1

Write-Output "*** 2. run inside if ****"
if (func1) {

}

# checking for func1 members - there are Boolean only value returned
$return_values = func1;
$return_values | Get-Member
```