# How to make this PowerShell function return a plain string, but not return an array of string?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, windows-8.1, powershell-4.0

Even though the `$logDir` variable contains the value `"C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logs"` (obtained from a text file), this code does not behave as I'd expect. It returns an array of strings, not a single string.

```
$LogFileName = "NoIP-update.log"
$ConfigSection = "NoIp"

function Log-Message ($MSG) {
    $script:Logger += "$(get-date -format u) $MSG`n"
    Write-Output $MSG
}

function Get-LogFileName ($config) {
    $Local:logDir = $config["Section"]["LOGDIR"]
    if ($Local:logDir -ne "") {
      Log-Message "Testing for directory '$Local:logDir'"
      if(!(Test-Path -Path $Local:logDir )){
          New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Local:logDir
          Log-Message "Created directory '$Local:logDir'"
      }
      return "$Local:logDir\$LogFileName"
    }
    return $LogFileName
}
```

I'm probably missing something very very basic, as I expect the function to return 1 string, not an array of strings and log one or two lines.

However, it doesn't log, and: if `$Local:logDir` exists, the function returns an array of 2 strings, otherwise it returns an array of 4 strings.

- Why?
- How can I make it return 1 string and still log?

I think it has to do with thinking using the pipelining metaphor versus my background in procedural and object oriented programming languages. Help is much appreciated (:

2-string array:

```
{Testing for directory 'C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logs', C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logs\NoIP-update.log}
```

4-string array:

```
{Testing for directory 'C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logs', C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Temp\logs, Created directory 'C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logs', C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logs\NoIP-update.log}
```

Notes:

- I run from within [PowerGUI](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/), but from the PowerShell console it has the same results.
- `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` returns `4.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I the issue is with `Log-Message` and specifically with the line `Write-Output`.

When you use `Write-Output` inside a function it is treated as a way to return a value from a function (i.e. it can be used interchangeably with `Return`). So what is happening is that your logging messages are being included in the `Return` stream.

If you are just wanting to display logging information to the display, use `Write-Host` instead. That will display information to the host, but not be included in your `Return` stream.

So the fix is to change your `Log-Message` function to:

```
function Log-Message ($MSG) {
    $script:Logger += "$(get-date -format u) $MSG`n"
    Write-Host $MSG
}
```

Comment: +1; accepted. Thanks a lot. Now I need to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline/8755614#8755614 and watch the video.