# More efficient way to write to an output file in Powershell needed

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a Powershell script i'm using to parse each row in a file, reformat it, and write the new string to an output file. It works fine with an input file with a few hundred lines. However, I need to ultimately run it against a file with a few million lines, and I have been waiting hours and it still hasn't finished. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline), I think I need to put Write-Output outside of the loop, but i've been unsuccessful so far.

This is my current code:

```
Foreach ($line in Get-Content $logFile) {

    $arr = $line.Split()

    $port1 = $arr[9].Split(":")

    $port2 = $arr[11].Split(":")

    $connstring = '|' + $port1[0] + "|" + $port1[1] + "|" + $port2[0] + "|" + $port2[1] + "|" + $arr[4] + "|"

    Write-Output $connstring | Out-File "C:\logging\output\logout.txt" -Append 
}
```

An example of an input string is:

```
06/14-04:40:11.371923  [**] [1:4:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 67.202.196.92:80 -> 192.168.1.105:55043
```

And I need to reformat it to this:

```
|67.202.196.92|80|192.168.1.105|55043|other|
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you only need to capture the IP/port and content after that?  A regex might be able to accomplish what you want faster.

Comment: Yes, correct. The IPs, ports and the tag (in this case 'other').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `-ReadCount` on the `Get-Content` it will have the effect of streaming the file one row at a time rather than having to read the entire file in to memory. I suspect that moving write operation outside of your loop might be faster. Less variables and steps inside your loop will probably help too.

Assuming the fourth element after the split doesn't contain a colon (you didn't supply and example of your file) then something like this is should do the trick:

```
Get-Content $logFile -ReadCount 1 | % {
    '|' + (($_.Split()[9, 11, 4] -replace ':', '|') -join '|') + '|' 
} | Out-File "C:\logging\output\logout.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you Dave; so far, my initial testing with your code seems a little faster  but unfortunately not by much. I've updated my original post with an example of an input string and the reformatted string. Perhaps my code logic needs tweaked?

Comment: Update, this code was substantially faster. Thank you Dave!

Answer (score 2):

It *might* help to remove the addition in your string construction

```
$connstring = "|$($port1[0])|$($port1[1])|$($port2[0])|$($port2[1])|$($arr[4])|"
```

Try using `Measure-Command` to test with sample data sets.

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this :

```
$test="06/14-04:40:11.371923  [**] [1:4:0] other [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 67.202.196.92:80 -> 192.168.1.105:55043"

$template=@"
{Row:06/14-04:40:11.371923  [**] [1:4:0] {Text:other} [**] [Priority: 0] \{TCP\} {IPIN:67.202.196.92}:{PORTIN:80} -> {IPOUT:192.168.1.105}:{PORTOUT:55043}}
"@

$test| ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template |%{"|{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}|" -f $_.Row.IPIN, $_.Row.PORTIN, $_.Row.IPOUT , $_.Row.PORTOUT , $_.Row.Text }
```

but you could export direectly to csv like this :

```
$template=@"
{Row:06/14-04:40:11.371923  [**] [1:4:0] {Text:other} [**] [Priority: 0] \{TCP\} {IPIN:67.202.196.92}:{PORTIN:80} -> {IPOUT:192.168.1.105}:{PORTOUT:55043}}
"@

Get-Content $logFile | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | % {
 [pscustomobject]@{
 IPIN=$_.Row.IPIN 
 PORTIN=$_.Row.PORTIN 
 IPOUT=$_.Row.IPOUT 
 PORTOUT=$_.Row.PORTOUT 
 Text=$_.Row.Text
 }

} | export-csv "C:\logging\output\logout.csv" -Append -NoType
```

Comment: In the second code the last line is an alternative foreach and should IMO be commented out/deleted. Otherwise +1 I think `ConvertFrom-String` with a template is heavily underestimated