# How to overwrite existing SSH key file using ssh-keygen and PowerShell without typing y

Tags: powershell, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-keygen

If I want to overwrite existing SSH key file without typing <kbd>y</kbd>, then I would do this in bash:

```
echo "y" | ssh-keygen -f /home/wakatana/id_rsa -N ""
```

How can same be achieved using PowerShell? I've tried following:

```
Write-Host "y" | ssh-keygen.exe -f C:\Users\wakatana\Desktop\id_rsa -N """"
```

It won't show me `Overwrite (y/n)?` dialog, but I does not rewrite existing key. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Output "y" | ssh-keygen.exe -f .\test -N "blahblah"
```

[image]

Comment: `Write-Output` is superfluous here.

Comment: Good point by @Bill_Stewart .  This should work as well:

`"y" | ssh-keygen.exe -f .\test -N "blahblah"`

Comment: thank you very much. This worked. Can you please explain why `Write-Host` is not working while `Write-Output` is?

Comment: @WakanTanka [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/whats-the-difference-between-write-host-write-output-or-consolewrite) is a good explanation.  

In my own words, `Write-Host` send output to the "host", which can vary, but is usually the command console.  `Write-Output` sends the output through the pipeline and to STDOUT, which is then interpreted as the STDIN for the next native command in the pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the file if it already exists, before calling `ssh-keygen`.

*Blindly sending "yes" to an application, without knowing, what does it ask in the first place, is quite dangerous.*

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `rm` the existing keys first?

Powershell (not a ps guru, so adjust to taste):

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\wakatana\Desktop\id_rsa && Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\wakatana\Desktop\id_rsa.pub && ssh-keygen.exe -f C:\Users\wakatana\Desktop\id_rsa -N """"
```

Linux (since I'm here and this is what *I came for*):

```
rm -f path/to/.ssh/id_rsa* && ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa -f path/to/.ssh/id_rsa
```

JIC any of this assists the next one to stop by. Keep on keepin' on, fellow devs =]

Edit: I read good. Just caught Martin Prikryl's answer. Same diff - hah!

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, just use yes|ssh-keygen ...